# Port Eclipse Problems view configuration to IDEA/Android studio

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea, code-analysis

I'm using Intellij IDEA/Android Studio.

I was asked not to make any commits unless my code doesn't trigger any warnings in Problems View of Eclipse IDE.

So, is there any quick way to port Eclipse's analysis configuration to IDEA?

Thanks.

Comment: In regards to the added bounty asking for an official or credible source... to get an "official" answer, I recommend you ask on the [IntelliJ IDEA Users](http://goo.gl/tt9vQN) forum. A JetBrains developer can confirm my answer. You can also look at the [Import Eclipse Workspace](http://goo.gl/tQLk2l) page in the web help and the [Eclipse FAQ](http://goo.gl/2moq8) wiki page. If such a feature existed, it would be documented there. As far as a "credible" source, my credentials at the official IntelliJ IDEA Users site speak for themselves. Cheers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is not. There is the [Eclipse Code Formatter](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6546?pr=idea) third party plug-in for portng over code formatting definitions. Pehaps you can contact that developer and see if he would add problems/inspections definition syncing. Until then, I see two options for you...

1. Configure your IDEA inspections so they match the team's Eclipse settings. This of course would require some time to initially set up. But I think in the end, it's the best solution.
2. IDEA can export to files in eclipse format. As part of that it can keep its configuration linked to the eclipse files. This way you could pop over to eclipse to check for problems prior to committing.